# Unable to get a value selected in a dropdown in an specific scenario

Tags: jsp, atg

I have a specific scenario. In my jsp, I have a  tag of following structure -

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${some_condition}">
        <dsp:select id="myId" bean="MyBean.property1">
            <dsp:option></option>
            ....
        </dsp:select>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <dsp:select id="myId" bean="MyBean.property2">
            <dsp:option></option>
            ....
        </dsp:select>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

When I visit the page for first time, say condition 'some_condition' is true and I select a value from this drop-down. This values passed to the server on form submit. Now if I navigate to the same page and this say the drop-down in otherwise section is loaded, if I select any option from this drop-down it is not getting passed to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `bean` attribute of `<dsp:select>` tag in `<c:otherwise>` to **MyBean.property1**

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${some_condition}">
    <dsp:select id="myId" bean="MyBean.property1">
        <dsp:option></option>
        ....
    </dsp:select>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <dsp:select id="myId" bean="MyBean.property1">
        <dsp:option></option>
        ....
    </dsp:select>
</c:otherwise>
```